# How to create Cash Register Effect using Pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to create a Cash Register Effect using Pure Javascript(With out using any libraries),

Here is the link for Cash register Effect which is implemented Using Mootools,

http://jsbin.com/ehuzes/edit#preview

I want to get this effect using raw Javascript. It will be huge help, If somebody gives the solution.

Comment: SO is not about "giving the solution". That's what you pay people for. It's for helping people reach a solution by themselves. Have you even tried to code up anything, or are you asking for a free-lunch?

Comment: That's more or less pure JavaScript. Just the event handler registration and the class creation seem to be done with Mootools (*edit* ok it extends Fx), but the most of the actual logic is plain JavaScript. Take some more time to understand the code...

Comment: @spender I mean i dont need any code, I just need some method to do it. I mean the algo. I have tried everything from morning. I was able to get it work. I did like used same mootools code and removed all the unwanted code from mootools and its working fine. But I wanted an algo to code it by Myself.The files i tried are pastebin.com/h9TTBpyU, and the modified mootools.js is pastebin.com/YwTb7vBL

Comment: @Felix Kling I tried understanding and i was able to get it running by stripping all the unwanted code from mootools.js, The files i tried are http://pastebin.com/h9TTBpyU, and the modified mootools.js is http://pastebin.com/YwTb7vBL, But after trying all these, I thought there will be simpler solution for this.Please give the algo i will do that.

Comment: There is no specific algorithm. You have a starting value and a target value. Every x milliseconds you increase the current value and write it until you reached the target value. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#number').on('change', function (e) {
    $(this).cashregister($(this).val());
});

(function ($) {
    $.fn.cashregister = function (num) {
        var output = $('#output').html();

        function intervalfunc(interval, num) {
            var end = parseInt($('#number').html());
            var cont =  parseInt($('#output').html())

            $('#output').html( cont + interval );
            if ( $('#output').html() == num ) {
                clearInterval(int);
                return false;
            }
        }

       if (num > output) {
           var int = setInterval(function() { intervalfunc(1, num) }, 0.1);    
       }else if (num < output) {
           var int = setInterval(function() { intervalfunc(-1, num) }, 0.1);        
       }else if (num == $('#output').html() ) {
           // do nothing
       }else{
          alert("Invalid Input!");
       }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DuLjC/3/ -> working version of suggested fix

Answer (score 0):

use an onclick function on a button or something, which should get the number (value from maybe a text box) and to send that variable to a defined function which uses .innerHTML on a div to change the number value, then you use `SetInterval` function to make the number go either up or down by 1 each interval. then use `clearInterval` when the number has been reached.

maybe something like:

```
<div id = "container">0</div>
<input type = 'text'
       id = 'number' />
<input type = 'button'
       value = 'change amount'
       onclick = "var num = document.getElementById('number').value;
                  cashregister(num);" />
```

for the HTML and:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
  function cashregister(num) {
    var cont = document.getElementById('container').innerHTML;
    if (num < cont) {
      var int = setInterval("intervalfunc(1)", (interval_time_in_miliseconds));
      function intervalfunc(num) {
        var end = document.getElementById('number');
        var cont = document.getElementById('cont').innerHTML;
        cont.innerHTML = cont + num;
        if (cont == end) {
          clearInterval(int);
        }
      }
    } else if (num > cont) {
      var int = setInterval("intervalfunc(-1)", (interval_time_in_miliseconds));
      function intervalfunc(num) {
        var end = document.getElementById('number');
        var cont = document.getElementById('cont').innerHTML;
        cont.innerHTML = cont + num;
        if (cont == end) {
          clearInterval(int);
        }
      }
    } else if (num == cont) {
      //do nothing
    } else {
      alert("invalid input!");
    }
  }

</script>
```

I'm not sure if this exact code will work but what you want is something along these lines.

Comment: Better use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` and don't pass strings to these functions.

Comment: but setting a setTimeout only executes it once, using setInterval creates a sort of animation of the numbers going up or down depending on how fast (or slow) it is timed

Comment: That's why you would call it again in your function, creating some kind of recursion. The problem with `setInterval` is that you might build a queue of functions because the time a function takes to run is longer than the intervall time.

Comment: I tried it, http://jsbin.com/ehidib/edit#preview, But its not working, I got some idea how i can do this. Thanks for the code.

Comment: If the interval is timed correctly that shouldn't be a problem, but using setTimeout multiple times would require you to specify each time, and wouldn't suit large numbers, since it's +1 every so many miliseconds. personally I prefer to use the plugins but this is just a rough work around.

Comment: no problem, as i said though it's just a rough work around, something i made up on the spot

Comment: oh and in your priview there you didn't change "interval_time_in_miliseconds" with  number (1000 being 1 second)

Comment: I need to use this Snippet with exactly these separators but i want it working automatically, once i land the page i need these numbers making this effect. Any suggestion on which part to delete to achieve that?

Comment: either put `var num = document.getElementById('number').value; cashregister(num);` in an onload event in the `<body>` tag or in jquery's `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 0):

I like this one by Nevan Scott: https://codepen.io/nevan/pen/uBkEr

```js
var total = 0;

document.getElementById('entry').onsubmit = enter;

function enter() {
  var entry = document.getElementById('newEntry').value;
  var entry = parseFloat(entry);
  currency = currencyFormat(entry);
  document.getElementById('entries').innerHTML += '<tr><td></td><td>' + currency + '</td></tr>';
  total += entry;
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = currencyFormat(total);
  
  document.getElementById('newEntry').value = '';
  return false;
}

function currencyFormat(number) {
  var currency = parseFloat(number);
  currency = currency.toFixed(2);
  currency = '$' + currency;
  return currency;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #EEE;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 3em;
  padding: 0;
}
#register {
  width: 20em;
  margin: auto;
}
#ticket {
  background: white;
  margin: 0 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}
#ticket h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
#ticket table {
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#ticket td, #ticket th {
  padding: 5px;
}
#ticket th {
  text-align: left;
}
#ticket td, #ticket #total {
  text-align: right;
}
#ticket tfoot th {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

#entry {
  background: #333;
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}
#entry input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#entry input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
}
```

```html
<div id="register">
  <div id="ticket">
    <h1>Thank You!</h1>
    <table>
      <tbody id="entries">
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Total</th>
          <th id="total">$0.00</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
  <form id="entry">
    <input id="newEntry" autofocus placeholder="How Much?">
  </form>
</div>
```